# Phpmyadmin MYSQL import: Certain characters are not imported

Tags: mysql, encoding, iso-8859-1, utf8mb4

I am migrating a wordpress site from one server to another. I exported an sql dump from the old server and imported it into the new server database through phpmyadmin. But certain characters are not displayed correctly like the apostrophe and hyphen.

I figure this is because of the different database encoding present in the 2 servers. The old server has the character set encoding as **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci** while the new server has the encoding **latin1_swedish_ci**.

I tried changing the "Character set of the file:" of the export dump by setting it to **iso-8859-1** so that it would then get imported correctly into the **latin1_swedish_ci** but it gives an error during import of the SQL syntax.

How can I migrate the data here correctly?

Comment: If you know what the old encoding was, why not use that on the new server

Comment: @RiggsFolly I dont have superadmin access to change the encoding on the new server

Comment: What parameters were used on the dump?  What was used on the load?  There is one way to get the dump+load to "do the right thing", and many ways to mess it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason to be using "latin1_swedish_ci" (and I can't imagine you do - it was the MySQL default at some point), you should not be using that at all.   Change the character set encoding on the new server to match the former.

Comment: I dont have superadmin access to change the encoding on the new server. I have changed the encoding of the tables so it works fine now for future data. But how do I correct the old data?

Comment: Data should never be 'changed' or 'corrected'; the database is the only source of truth. You should not be altering the data whatsoever. Find out who has proper access to change the character set encoding, and get them to do so.  "latin1_swedish_ci" is a generally useless encoding, and you should be doing things the proper way.

Comment: Lol. Well said. Did exactly the way you said